# Why does my MySQL remote-connection fail (VLAN)?

Tags: networking, mysql, remote-access, lan

Again I have a problem with my special friend MySQL :D
I have got two servers - a database-server and a web-server - which are connected via VLAN.

Now I want the web-server to have remote access to the database-server's MySQL. So I created the user *user* in *mysql.user*.

*user*'s Host is xxx.yyy.zzz.9 which is the internal IP-address of the web-server.

xxx.yyy.zzz.0 is the network. I also created *user* with Host *%* .

As long as I use MySQL on the database-server logging in as *user*, everything works fine. But trying to log in as *user* from xxx.yyy.zzz.9 using

```
mysql -h xxx.yyy.zzz.8 -u user -p
```

(where xxx.yyy.zzz.8 is the database-server's internal IP), I get

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.yyy.zzz.8' (110)
```

So I tried to activate `Bind-Address` in the my.cnf file. Well, if I use xxx.yyy.zzz.8, nothing changes. But if I try xxx.yyy.zzz.9 and try to restart MySQL, I get

```
mysql stop/waiting
start: Job failed to start
```

I checked the log files and found - nothing. The database-server's MySQL doesn't even register, that the web-server tries to connect remotely.

My idea is that maybe I didn't configure the VLAN properly, even though I asked someone who actually knows such stuff and he told me I did everything right.

What I wrote in `/etc/networking/interfaces` is:

```
#The VLAN
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address xxx.yyy.zzz..8
netmask 255.255.255.0
network xxx.yyy.zzz.0
broadcast xxx.yyy.zzz.255
mtu 1500
```

`ifconfig` returns

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
          inet addr:xxx.yyy.zzz.8  Bcast:xxx.yyy.zzz.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:241146 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9765 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17825995 (17.8 MB)  TX bytes:566602 (566.6 KB)
          Memory:fb900000-fb920000
```

for the eth1, what is, what I configured. (This is for the database-server, the web-server looks similar).

`ethtool eth1` returns:

```
Settings for eth1:

    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: d
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000003 (3)
                           drv probe
    Link detected: yes
```

(This is for the database-server, the web-server looks similar).

I commented out `Bind-Address` in my.cnf after it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

The service `psa-firewall`, which is activated and configured by Plesk, was running. It refused every incoming MySQL request.

I reconfigured it via Plesk, allowing it to let MySQL requests to go through. I don't know if I could also have done it in the shell, but deactivating it definitely helped! Yet I think that might be kind of dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is listening by default only on loopback interface. So even with a user with right privilege, you will be unable to access remotely on your mysql server. Additionnaly, the bind-address option in not dedicated to give access on some host, but to specify the interface to listen.

So first check your mysql is listening on loopback interface

```
netstat -tnl | grep 3306
```

You will see something like that

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

If right, you have to change mysql configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Then search for the line :

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Then replace `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`. You will obtain the line :

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Restart Mysql to take effect

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

End check that Mysql is listening on all interfaces

```
netstat -tnl | grep 3306
```

You should see :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: Hm ..using        
    

        `netstat -tnl | grep 3306`


already returned


       `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306    0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN` 


This might be because I commented out `Bind-Address` earlier, sorry I didn't mention that.        
I also tried 


        `netstat -ln | grep mysql`


Because the MySQL-documentation advised it :-P
It returned:
        

        `unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     280092   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.socket`


Does that have anything to do with my problem?

Comment: intereseting: changing Bind-Address to 0.0.0.0 also leads to `start:Job failed to start` when I use `service mysql restart`